# Best way to check if file matching abc* exists in a particular directory

Tags: c++, file

I want to know how to check if a file matching `core*` exists in `/tmp/` path. The actual file can be anything like below.

- `corexyz.txt`
- `coreabc.tar.gz`
- `core*`

If the complete file name was known, I could have used `stat` or `access` to know if the file existed. But here, I want to know if there is any file matching `core*`.

```
bool checkFile (std::string ABC)
{
    return true; /* return true if file ABC* exists */
}
```

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you can use c++17 the [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) will be interesting for you.

You can use [std::filesystem::directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) to iterate over all the files in a directory and check if they start with the given prefix using [path.filename()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename).